# To print factors of given number in C

Tags: c

I'm trying to print the factors of a given number in C. But when I enter a number in console, nothing happens.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    int n;
    printf("enter the number ");
    scanf("%d ", &n);
    for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        if(n % i == 0) {
            printf("%d", i);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try printing with a newline after it: `printf("%d\n", i);`

Comment: You should be storing the return value of `scanf` as it tells you how many items it was able to successfully scan. Something like `int itemsScanned = scanf("%d ", &n)`. Then if `itemsScanned` is non-zero, you actually scanned something successfully into `n`. If you do this, you'll see that your code is not successfully scanning input, which is because your format specifier includes a space "%d " instead of "%d"

Comment: @h0r53: Re “If you do this, you'll see that your code is not successfully scanning input”: No, they will not. Once `printf` scans a number and then starts scanning as directed by the space, either it will not stop because there is no non-space character to scan or it will stop and return 1 because one value was assigned for the `%d`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I believe you mean `scanf`

Answer (score 1):

This is why your code isn't working as you expected:

```c
scanf("%d ",&n);
```

Change it to:

```c
scanf("%d", &n); // Remove the space after %d
```

The reason is that `scanf("%d ", &n)` expects an `int` followed by one or more whitespaces. A whitespace can either be a  , a tab `\t` or a newline `\n`. When you enter a number and then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, `scanf()` normally consumes everything up to a newline, but in this case it also consumes the newline(s), so it continues to wait for input until you enter a non-whitespace character.

Comment: Answers should explain, not just say how to correct the code.

Comment: @EricPostpischil OK I will explain.

Comment: Also worth noting, `scanf` returns a **very valuable value** indicating the number of items successfully scanned/parsed.

Comment: Re “`scanf()` normally consumes everything up to a newline”: For `scanf("%d", &n);`, `scanf` will consume initial space characters and then characters until it reads one which cannot be part of a decimal numeral. This could be a new-line character, but it could be a space, tab, letter, punctuation mark, or other character. `scanf` would not care. It then puts the unaccepted character back into the input stream, so it is not consumed.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple problems in the code:

- `scanf("%d ", &n);` will convert user input as an integer in base 10 and attempt to consume any whitespace characters that follow. Hence `scanf()` will not return until the user types a non whitespace character... causing the program to appear to do *nothing* after you hit the <kbd>enter</kbd> key. This key produces a newline (`'\n'`) character in the input stream, which is a whitespace character. Remove the trailing space in `"%d "` to fix this problem.
- you should test the return value of `scanf("%d", &n)` to check that a number was successfully converted by `scanf`. The return value will be `1` if so, or `0` if the first non whitespace character entered is not a digit nor a sign, and `EOF` if the end of file is reached before a number can be converted.
- `printf("%d", i)` does not output a space or a newline after the number, so all factors will be output as a single string of digits.

Here is a corrected version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int n;
    printf("enter the number ");
    if (scanf("%d", &n) == 1) {
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            if (n % i == 0) {
                printf("%d\n", i);
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you intend to keep the space in `scanf`?

Comment: @EricPostpischil: no I did not... Thanks for watching :)

Comment: After the `printf`, don't we need `n /= i--;` to catch all the factors? Otherwise, we have `8 --> 2 4` instead of `8 --> 2 2 2`?

Comment: @CraigEstey: the question is unclear to this regard. As coded, the program will print the divisors, not the prime factors. To get the prime factors, one could indeed add this statement after the `printf()`.